# Build NopCommerce project in an Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, nopcommerce, nopcommerce-4.1

I have been trying to create a build pipeline for a NopCommerce project, is the 4.1.3 version so it's built on dotnet.

After trying several .yml, I ended trying the most simple option and even then, doesn't work.

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'  

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreInstaller@0
  inputs:
    version: '2.1.3'

- script: dotnet build
  displayName: Build script
  workingDirectory: src/
```

I first install the dotnet version, and then just make a `'dotnet build'` command at solution level 'src/'.
It does restore all nugets from projects, but then fail to build the presentation projects.

Here is the log:

```
##[section]Starting: Build script
==============================================================================
Task         : Command Line
Description  : Run a command line script using cmd.exe on Windows and bash on macOS and Linux.
Version      : 2.148.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613735)
==============================================================================
Generating script.
Script contents:
dotnet build
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
##[command]"C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "d:\a\_temp\cc9c13cc-35a3-4844-a87e-b59c783d46d4.cmd""
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.9.20+g88f5fadfbe for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Restoring packages for D:\a\1\s\src\Libraries\Nop.Data\Nop.Data.csproj...
  Restoring packages for D:\a\1\s\src\Libraries\Nop.Core\Nop.Core.csproj...
  Installing System.Security.AccessControl 4.4.0.
  ...
  Generating MSBuild file D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.CheckMoneyOrder\obj\Nop.Plugin.Payments.CheckMoneyOrder.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
  Restore completed in 413.98 ms for D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.CheckMoneyOrder\Nop.Plugin.Payments.CheckMoneyOrder.csproj.
  ...
  Restore completed in 683.38 ms for D:\a\1\s\src\Tests\Nop.Web.MVC.Tests\Nop.Web.MVC.Tests.csproj.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.105\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets(153,5): warning NETSDK1071: A PackageReference to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App' specified a Version of `2.1.2`. Specifying the version of this package is not recommended. For more information, see https://aka.ms/sdkimplicitrefs [D:\a\1\s\src\Libraries\Nop.Core\Nop.Core.csproj]
  Nop.Core -> D:\a\1\s\src\Libraries\Nop.Core\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\Nop.Core.dll
  Nop.Data -> D:\a\1\s\src\Libraries\Nop.Data\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\Nop.Data.dll
  Nop.Services -> D:\a\1\s\src\Libraries\Nop.Services\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\Nop.Services.dll
  Nop.Plugin.ExchangeRate.EcbExchange -> D:\a\1\s\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\ExchangeRate.EcbExchange\Nop.Plugin.ExchangeRate.EcbExchange.dll
  The application to execute does not exist: 'D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.dll'   
D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.proj(21,5): error MSB3073: The command "dotnet "D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.dll" "OutputPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Build\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\|PluginPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Shipping.FixedByWeightByTotal\..\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Shipping.FixedByWeightByTotal\|SaveLocalesFolders="" exited with code -2147450751.
  Nop.Plugin.Pickup.PickupInStore -> D:\a\1\s\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Pickup.PickupInStore\Nop.Plugin.Pickup.PickupInStore.dll
  The application to execute does not exist: 'D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.dll'

D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.proj(21,5): error MSB3073: The command "dotnet "D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.dll" "OutputPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Build\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\|PluginPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Pickup.PickupInStore\..\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Pickup.PickupInStore\|SaveLocalesFolders="" exited with code -2147450751.      
D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.proj(21,5): error MSB3073: The command "dotnet "D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.dll" "OutputPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Build\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\|PluginPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Widgets.NivoSlider\..\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Widgets.NivoSlider\|SaveLocalesFolders="" exited with code -2147450751.
  Nop.Plugin.ExternalAuth.Facebook -> D:\a\1\s\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\ExternalAuth.Facebook\Nop.Plugin.ExternalAuth.Facebook.dll
  The application to execute does not exist: 'D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.dll'

D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.proj(21,5): error MSB3073: The command "dotnet "D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.dll" "OutputPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Build\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\|PluginPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.ExternalAuth.Facebook\..\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\ExternalAuth.Facebook\|SaveLocalesFolders="" exited with code -2147450751.    

D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.proj(21,5): error MSB3073: The command "dotnet "D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.dll" "OutputPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Build\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\|PluginPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.PayPalStandard\..\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Payments.PayPalStandard\|SaveLocalesFolders="" exited with code -2147450751.
  Nop.Plugin.Payments.CheckMoneyOrder -> D:\a\1\s\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Payments.CheckMoneyOrder\Nop.Plugin.Payments.CheckMoneyOrder.dll
  The application to execute does not exist: 'D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.dll'

D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.proj(21,5): error MSB3073: The command "dotnet "D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.dll" "OutputPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Build\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\|PluginPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.CheckMoneyOrder\..\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Payments.CheckMoneyOrder\|SaveLocalesFolders="" exited with code -2147450751.
  Nop.Plugin.Shipping.UPS -> D:\a\1\s\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Shipping.UPS\Nop.Plugin.Shipping.UPS.dll
  The application to execute does not exist: 'D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.dll'

D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.proj(21,5): error MSB3073: The command "dotnet "D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.dll" "OutputPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Build\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\|PluginPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Shipping.UPS\..\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Shipping.UPS\|SaveLocalesFolders="" exited with code -2147450751.
  Nop.Plugin.Payments.Manual -> D:\a\1\s\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Payments.Manual\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Manual.dll
  The application to execute does not exist: 'D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.dll'

D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.proj(21,5): error MSB3073: The command "dotnet "D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.dll" "OutputPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Build\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\|PluginPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Manual\..\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Payments.Manual\|SaveLocalesFolders="" exited with code -2147450751.
  Nop.Web -> D:\a\1\s\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\Nop.Web.dll
  The application to execute does not exist: 'D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.dll'

D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.proj(21,5): error MSB3073: The command "dotnet "D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.dll" "OutputPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Build\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\|PluginPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\DiscountRules.CustomerRoles\;D:\a\1\s\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\ExchangeRate.EcbExchange\;D:\a\1\s\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\ExternalAuth.Facebook\;D:\a\1\s\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Payments.CheckMoneyOrder\;D:\a\1\s\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Payments.Manual\;D:\a\1\s\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Payments.PayPalStandard\;D:\a\1\s\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Payments.Square\;D:\a\1\s\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Payments.Worldpay\;D:\a\1\s\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Pickup.PickupInStore\;D:\a\1\s\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Shipping.FixedByWeightByTotal\;D:\a\1\s\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Shipping.UPS\;D:\a\1\s\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Tax.FixedOrByCountryStateZip\;D:\a\1\s\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Widgets.GoogleAnalytics\;D:\a\1\s\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Widgets.NivoSlider\|SaveLocalesFolders="" exited with code -2147450751.
  Nop.Services.Tests -> D:\a\1\s\src\Tests\Nop.Services.Tests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\Nop.Services.Tests.dll
  Nop.Core.Tests -> D:\a\1\s\src\Tests\Nop.Core.Tests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\Nop.Core.Tests.dll
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.105\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Square.Connect". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square.csproj]
Domain\ExtendedChargeRequest.cs(3,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Square' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square.csproj]
Services\SquarePaymentManager.cs(12,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Square' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square.csproj]
Services\SquarePaymentManager.cs(13,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Square' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square.csproj]
Services\SquarePaymentManager.cs(14,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Square' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square.csproj]
SquarePaymentMethod.cs(25,21): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Square' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square.csproj]
Domain\ExtendedChargeRequest.cs(10,42): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ChargeRequest' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square.csproj]
Domain\ExtendedChargeRequest.cs(16,13): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Money' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square.csproj]
Domain\ExtendedChargeRequest.cs(23,13): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Address' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square.csproj]
Domain\ExtendedChargeRequest.cs(24,13): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Address' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square.csproj]
Domain\ExtendedChargeRequest.cs(27,18): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AdditionalRecipient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square.csproj]
Services\SquarePaymentManager.cs(59,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Configuration' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square.csproj]
Services\SquarePaymentManager.cs(87,22): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Location' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square.csproj]
Services\SquarePaymentManager.cs(129,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Customer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square.csproj]
Services\SquarePaymentManager.cs(169,40): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CreateCustomerRequest' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square.csproj]
Services\SquarePaymentManager.cs(169,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Customer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square.csproj]
Services\SquarePaymentManager.cs(206,59): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CreateCustomerCardRequest' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square.csproj]
Services\SquarePaymentManager.cs(206,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Card' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square.csproj]
Services\SquarePaymentManager.cs(246,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Transaction' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square.csproj]
Services\SquarePaymentManager.cs(296,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Transaction' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square.csproj]
Services\SquarePaymentManager.cs(449,68): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CreateRefundRequest' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square.csproj]
Services\SquarePaymentManager.cs(449,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Refund' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square.csproj]
  Nop.Plugin.Payments.Worldpay -> D:\a\1\s\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Payments.Worldpay\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Worldpay.dll
  The application to execute does not exist: 'D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.dll'

D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.proj(21,5): error MSB3073: The command "dotnet "D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.dll" "OutputPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Build\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\|PluginPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Worldpay\..\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Payments.Worldpay\|SaveLocalesFolders="" exited with code -2147450751.
  Nop.Web.MVC.Tests -> D:\a\1\s\src\Tests\Nop.Web.MVC.Tests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\Nop.Web.MVC.Tests.dll

Build FAILED.

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.105\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets(153,5): warning NETSDK1071: A PackageReference to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App' specified a Version of `2.1.2`. Specifying the version of this package is not recommended. For more information, see https://aka.ms/sdkimplicitrefs [D:\a\1\s\src\Libraries\Nop.Core\Nop.Core.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.105\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Square.Connect". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square.csproj]
D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.proj(21,5): error MSB3073: The command "dotnet "D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.dll" "OutputPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Build\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\|PluginPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.ExchangeRate.EcbExchange\..\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\ExchangeRate.EcbExchange\|SaveLocalesFolders="" exited with code -2147450751.
D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.proj(21,5): error MSB3073: The command "dotnet "D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.dll" "OutputPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Build\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\|PluginPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.DiscountRules.CustomerRoles\..\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\DiscountRules.CustomerRoles\|SaveLocalesFolders="" exited with code -2147450751.
D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.proj(21,5): error MSB3073: The command "dotnet "D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.dll" "OutputPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Build\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\|PluginPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Tax.FixedOrByCountryStateZip\..\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Tax.FixedOrByCountryStateZip\|SaveLocalesFolders="" exited with code -2147450751.
D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.proj(21,5): error MSB3073: The command "dotnet "D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.dll" "OutputPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Build\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\|PluginPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Shipping.FixedByWeightByTotal\..\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Shipping.FixedByWeightByTotal\|SaveLocalesFolders="" exited with code -2147450751.
D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.proj(21,5): error MSB3073: The command "dotnet "D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.dll" "OutputPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Build\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\|PluginPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Pickup.PickupInStore\..\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Pickup.PickupInStore\|SaveLocalesFolders="" exited with code -2147450751.
D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.proj(21,5): error MSB3073: The command "dotnet "D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.dll" "OutputPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Build\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\|PluginPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Widgets.NivoSlider\..\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Widgets.NivoSlider\|SaveLocalesFolders="" exited with code -2147450751.
D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.proj(21,5): error MSB3073: The command "dotnet "D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.dll" "OutputPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Build\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\|PluginPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.ExternalAuth.Facebook\..\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\ExternalAuth.Facebook\|SaveLocalesFolders="" exited with code -2147450751.
D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.proj(21,5): error MSB3073: The command "dotnet "D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.dll" "OutputPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Build\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\|PluginPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Widgets.GoogleAnalytics\..\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Widgets.GoogleAnalytics\|SaveLocalesFolders="" exited with code -2147450751.
D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.proj(21,5): error MSB3073: The command "dotnet "D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.dll" "OutputPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Build\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\|PluginPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.PayPalStandard\..\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Payments.PayPalStandard\|SaveLocalesFolders="" exited with code -2147450751.
D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.proj(21,5): error MSB3073: The command "dotnet "D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.dll" "OutputPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Build\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\|PluginPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.CheckMoneyOrder\..\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Payments.CheckMoneyOrder\|SaveLocalesFolders="" exited with code -2147450751.
D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.proj(21,5): error MSB3073: The command "dotnet "D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.dll" "OutputPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Build\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\|PluginPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Shipping.UPS\..\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Shipping.UPS\|SaveLocalesFolders="" exited with code -2147450751.
D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.proj(21,5): error MSB3073: The command "dotnet "D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.dll" "OutputPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Build\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\|PluginPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Manual\..\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Payments.Manual\|SaveLocalesFolders="" exited with code -2147450751.
D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.proj(21,5): error MSB3073: The command "dotnet "D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.dll" "OutputPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Build\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\|PluginPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\DiscountRules.CustomerRoles\;D:\a\1\s\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\ExchangeRate.EcbExchange\;D:\a\1\s\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\ExternalAuth.Facebook\;D:\a\1\s\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Payments.CheckMoneyOrder\;D:\a\1\s\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Payments.Manual\;D:\a\1\s\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Payments.PayPalStandard\;D:\a\1\s\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Payments.Square\;D:\a\1\s\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Payments.Worldpay\;D:\a\1\s\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Pickup.PickupInStore\;D:\a\1\s\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Shipping.FixedByWeightByTotal\;D:\a\1\s\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Shipping.UPS\;D:\a\1\s\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Tax.FixedOrByCountryStateZip\;D:\a\1\s\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Widgets.GoogleAnalytics\;D:\a\1\s\src\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Widgets.NivoSlider\|SaveLocalesFolders="" exited with code -2147450751.
Domain\ExtendedChargeRequest.cs(3,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Square' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square.csproj]
Services\SquarePaymentManager.cs(12,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Square' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square.csproj]
Services\SquarePaymentManager.cs(13,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Square' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square.csproj]
Services\SquarePaymentManager.cs(14,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Square' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square.csproj]
SquarePaymentMethod.cs(25,21): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Square' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square.csproj]
Domain\ExtendedChargeRequest.cs(10,42): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ChargeRequest' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square.csproj]
Domain\ExtendedChargeRequest.cs(16,13): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Money' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square.csproj]
Domain\ExtendedChargeRequest.cs(23,13): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Address' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square.csproj]
Domain\ExtendedChargeRequest.cs(24,13): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Address' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square.csproj]
Domain\ExtendedChargeRequest.cs(27,18): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AdditionalRecipient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square.csproj]
Services\SquarePaymentManager.cs(59,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Configuration' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square.csproj]
Services\SquarePaymentManager.cs(87,22): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Location' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square.csproj]
Services\SquarePaymentManager.cs(129,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Customer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square.csproj]
Services\SquarePaymentManager.cs(169,40): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CreateCustomerRequest' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square.csproj]
Services\SquarePaymentManager.cs(169,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Customer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square.csproj]
Services\SquarePaymentManager.cs(206,59): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CreateCustomerCardRequest' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square.csproj]
Services\SquarePaymentManager.cs(206,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Card' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square.csproj]
Services\SquarePaymentManager.cs(246,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Transaction' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square.csproj]
Services\SquarePaymentManager.cs(296,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Transaction' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square.csproj]
Services\SquarePaymentManager.cs(449,68): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CreateRefundRequest' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square.csproj]
Services\SquarePaymentManager.cs(449,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Refund' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Square.csproj]
D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.proj(21,5): error MSB3073: The command "dotnet "D:\a\1\s\src\Build\ClearPluginAssemblies.dll" "OutputPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Build\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\|PluginPath=D:\a\1\s\src\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Payments.Worldpay\..\..\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Payments.Worldpay\|SaveLocalesFolders="" exited with code -2147450751.
    2 Warning(s)
    35 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:02:03.07
##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1'.
##[section]Finishing: Build script
```

I had to delete part of the log, It was to long.

Answer (score 0):

Try using DotNetCoreCLI tasks.

This is our working yaml (with pipeline references variables):

```
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Restore
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: '$(Parameters.RestoreBuildProjects)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    projects: '$(Parameters.RestoreBuildProjects)'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Publish
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: True
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: True

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Below YAML pipeline runs successfully for a nopCommmerce project (4.70.0 version) that runs with .NET 7.

#### azure-pipelines.yml

```yaml
# ASP.NET
# Build and test ASP.NET projects.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-4

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet restore'
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: ./src/NopCommerce.sln

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet build'
  inputs:
    projects: ./src/NopCommerce.sln
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet test'
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: |
     ./src/Tests/Nop.Core.Tests/Nop.Core.Tests.csproj
     ./src/Tests/Nop.Web.MVC.Tests/Nop.Web.MVC.Tests.csproj
     ./src/Tests/Nop.Services.Tests/Nop.Services.Tests.csproj
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet publish'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    ArtifactName: '$(Parameters.ArtifactName)'
```

and here's the proof.
[image]